# Python gives TypeError while parsing request.data

Tags: python, json, for-loop

From my React App, I'm getting the following Json via my Django API's backend.

```
{'0': {'title': 'The Title?', 'text': 'rdhdrhdr'}, '1': {'title': 'The Title2', 'text': 'hdrhdhdrh'}}
```

I then try to iterate some data via a for loop,

```
def post(self, request):
    data = request.data
    print(data)
    for a in data:
       print(a['title'])
```

Where I expect it to print The Title and The Title2, I get the following error.

```
    print(a['title'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I assume something is wrong with my json.. but can't figure it out.

Comment: 1. Your data is not JSON, it's a Python dictionary. 2. When doing `for a in data:` you are iterating over the **keys** not the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating over the keys of the dictionary, instead of the data. What you want to do is:

```py
def post(self, request):
    data = request.data
    print(data)
    for a in data.values():
       print(a['title'])
```